# django search function , models are not working

Tags: python, django

```
    @login_required
def searchProduct(request):
    """
    to search a particular product with name
    """
    search_terms =''
    if request.GET['search_term']:
        search_terms = request.GET.get('search_term')
        if search_terms:
            products = models.Product.objects.filter(product_name__icontains=search_terms)
            for product in products:
                kitchenstyle = KicthenStyleMapping.objects.filter(product= product)              
                print kitchenstyle

            return render_to_response('admin/product/searchListProduct.html',{'search_terms': search_terms,'products' : products }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

class KicthenStyleMapping(models.Model):
    style_mapping_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    style = models.ForeignKey(KitchenStyle)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'kicthen_style_mapping'

    class KitchenStyle(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    style_name = models.CharField(max_length=248L, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    estimated_time = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'kitchen_style'

    class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cabinet = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materials)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, null=True, blank=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    descriptions = models.TextField(blank=True)
    product_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    min_height = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    max_height = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    height_scale = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    min_width = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    max_width = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    width_scale = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    min_depth = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    max_depth = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    depth_scale = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_hinges = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    is_door = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    discount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_drawer = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=200L, blank=True)
    is_custom = models.CharField(max_length=4L)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'product'
```

i am a new bie in django. i am not using django search or any other inbuilt search modules. 
here in search product function i cant filter the kitchenstylemapping model with product field as the foreign key.
any help appreciated

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: This is where you start debugging. What objects do you get in your "products" variable? Check your input, are they what you think they are? Try running just smaller parts of your code and you'll find where things go wrong.

Comment: my inputs are simple words which are for searching products. i got it working

Comment: my question is whether i can group the products of same style , and get an object of the resultusing filter in KicthenStyleMapping

Comment: now i am getting the results but i cannot sort based on style type

Answer (score 0):

This link: [Django Query Set API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) is your new best friend.

Django comes with fantastic documentation and you should take full advantage of it. E.g The double underscore in the filter means that Django can lookup foreign keys; it's is powerful, but not very pretty.

The easiest way I've found of writing queries is to open up a shell:

```
python manage.py shell
from (your model file) myapp.models import *

KitchenStyle.objects.filter(style_set__product_name__icontains=searchterms)
```

and then learn your way around the filter syntax.

Use things like `dir(your_object)` to get an idea of the kind of fields it has and can be queried, they won't all make sense right away, but it's a good place to start.

Hope that helps.